# Is go get needed in order to use packages

Tags: layout, go, package

Is it needed to `go get` on packages? My code is here: https://github.com/retep-mathwizard/utils

My packages have dependencies on other items

Comment: Can you please clarify the question?

Comment: Sorry about that, just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go get will checkout the needed dependencies for them. For instance when I go get one of your packages via:

go get github.com/retep-mathwizard/utils/convert

go also gets the skilstak resource because your package is dependent on it.

The go get [documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/) says:

Get downloads and installs the packages named by the import paths, along with their dependencies.